# Why does ctime returns the same string for different time_t values?

Tags: c++, time

I have a function which prints time_t values.

```
void Logger::describe()
    {
        cout << m_start_time << " " << m_end_time << "\n";
            if (ctime(&m_start_time) == ctime(&m_end_time))
            {
                cout << "check1\n";
            }
            cout << m_vehicle->getPlate() << " " << ctime(&m_start_time) << " " << ctime(&m_end_time) << "\n";
    }

// m_start_time and m_end_time are private variables of type time_t of the class Logger
```

For a sample output after waiting a couple of seconds I get

```
1634907786 1634907791
check1
bike1 Fri Oct 22 18:33:06 2021
 Fri Oct 22 18:33:06 2021
```

As can be seen **m_start_time** and **m_end_time** are different but ctime returns the the same value. Can anyone help explain why ?

I'm using gcc 6.3.0 if it helps.

Comment: `ctime` returns a `char*`, i.e. a pointer to a string buffer. The function does not have to be thread safe. Therefore the same buffer might be reused. You should print the first result before you call again. Also: You only compare buffers, not string content. At least when it comes to C which you have tagged your question with.

Comment: This is clearly not C.

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm using  C++, updated tags. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You want to use [ctime_r(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime_r.3.html) with two *different* preallocated buffers

Answer (score 4):

Read the information on the return value here: [ctime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime)

It is a pointer to a static string. You are not comparing the string content (see [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)), only this pointer.

Comment: that and `... << ctime(&m_start_time) << " " << ctime(&m_end_time) << "\n";` prints the same string

Comment: demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Pz1E9Y9TK